# Do you mind if I did or do something

Tags: tense

> Do you mind if I tried this shirt on?
>
> Do you mind if I take your ticket?

Why these two sentences used different tenses, and is there any different meaning, especially when speaking about a happening act, like trying on， they used a past tense？

Comment: the first sentence is wrong i think, it would normally be "try this shirt on". Can you provide context please, where did you see these 2 sentences.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I think the questions sound better when the present tense is used with *do*, but the past tense is used with *would*:

> Do you mind if I **try** this shirt on?
>   Would you mind if I **tried** this shirt on?
>
> Do you mind if I **take** your ticket?
>   Would you mind if I **took** your ticket?

but I’m not prepared to vehemently argue that those are the only grammatically correct way to phrase the two questions.

But I do know we could restructure the question like this:

> If I took your ticket, would you mind?

and I believe that forms a [Type 2 interrogative conditional](https://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/type-2-conditional/).

If we try to do the same thing with the “do” questions, the result doesn’t sound as natural:

> If I try this shirt on, do you mind?

However, I believe one could reasonably argue that beginning a question with “Do you mind if...” is idiomatic in at least some dialects of conversational English. If I was working on the floor of a clothing store, for example, and a customer asked, “Do you mind if I try this shirt on?” I don’t think I’d respond by correcting their grammar.

Comment: In the case of "Do you mind if I tried this shirt on?", if you didn't ask, you would have to put the shirt on to find out if the person had a problem with it, which would then have been in the past. The question form just asks permission to avoid a possible conflict. Even if he said "no", he might change his mind after the fact.